# Trying to compare two elements of arrays of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays

I currently have two arrays declared as:
char* arrs[1000][1000];
char* arrj[1000][1000];
I have filled up these two arrays with names and now I must compare for example, the first element of arrs and the third element of arrj. How can I do this? I have tried to use strcmp and have also tried (arrs[0] == arrj[2]) with no luck. My goal is to check if the corresponding elements are equal. (for reference: arrs[0] = Bob and arrj[2] = Tom)

Comment: Remove the `*` because I doubt you have a million elements of pointer to `char`. Anyway, try small before you risk breaking the machine with large. Start with say 3 arrays, for "Tom", "Bob" and "Harry" none of which has 999 characters.

Comment: A million pointers in each array of arrays?. I pray these aren't automatic variables in some function.

Comment: An array of arrays of pointers to char? You're surely making it wrong. Define them as `char arr[xxx][yyy]` (drop the asterisk), then use `strcmp(arrs[a], arrj[b])`.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `*` first, and also define index as much as you need, dont use that much first.

Hope this might help you.
I use scan only to know which index you wanna check, then use `strcmp` to compare 2 strings.
`strcmp(string1, string2) == 0` means if it's true

```
    char arrs[3][10] = {"Tom", "Bob", "Harry"};
    char arrj[3][10] = {"Harry", "Tom", "Bob"};

    int index1;
    int index2;

    printf("Input ArrayS Index : ");
    scanf("%d", &index1);fflush(stdin);
    printf("Input ArrayJ Index : ");
    scanf("%d", &index2);fflush(stdin);

    if(strcmp(arrs[index1], arrj[index2]) == 0){
        printf("%s - %s : Same Value", arrs[index1], arrj[index2]);
    }
    else {
        printf("%s - %s : Different Value", arrs[index1], arrj[index2]);
    }
```